# Hide div if no parameters are set

Tags: javascript, html

I am having some issues hiding a div whenever no parameters are set.
My current url is `https://example.com/player.php?ch=` and also have a div with the id `hideNoParam`

My current code is as follows

```
if(location.search == "?ch="){
  $('#hideNoParam').hide();
}
```

but this does not work as intended.

What I'd like it to do is whenever the URL is just `https://example.com/player.php` or `https://example.com/player.php?ch=` that the div `hideNoParam` is NOT visible, but whenever the URL is `https://example.com/player.php?ch=something` then it is visible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following way with [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object:

```js
var loc = 'https://example.com/player.php?ch=';
var url = new URL(loc);
var c = url.searchParams.get("ch");

if(!c){
 $('#hideNoParam').hide();
}

// with param
var loc2 = 'https://example.com/player.php?ch=hello';
var url2 = new URL(loc2);
var c2 = url2.searchParams.get("ch");
if(!c2){
 $('#hideNoParam2').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hideNoParam">Test Container</div>

<div id="hideNoParam2">Test container is shown because the parameter has value</div>
```

Comment: This isn't working unfortunately. The div is always shown no matter if a param is set or not.

Comment: @JanHenning, The answer snippet shows that the `div` is not showing.....

Comment: It's hiding at all times now, not only when no params are set.

Comment: @JanHenning, no.. it should not....check my updated answer with parameter value...

Comment: I am somehow not getting it to work. It's either visible at all times or not at all. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @JanHenning, I think the problem is with the variable name `location`. Try any other name for variable.....

Comment: Appreciate your help. How would I wrap the two divs around the content? Is it possible to do this with only using 1 div? -- The way I have it set up now #hideNoParam warps #hideNoParam2 which then wraps the content, and this works fine except its visible when no param, hidden when param is there.